# cortex-m4 Linux kernel "svc #0" line causes PC to be 0

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, stm32

I've faced with the following trouble. I try debugging "vmlinux" kernel (4.4.5 from kernel.org) build for arm7m architecture with debug info on.

I set by hands parameters via `r0=0, r1=0, r2=0x8004000`. My problem is when it reaches line 108 of "arch/arm/mm/proc-v7m.S" which is "svc #0" PC changes to `0x0` and everything ends.

My board is stm32f429-disc1. Kernel is located in flash starting at 0x8008000. Bootloader initializes clock, USART, SDRAM and calls the kernel.

The code around the fail line is the following :-

```
 107. cpsie i
 108. svc #0
 109. cpsid i
```

So I expected the conttroller to jump to SVC ISR instead of changing PC to 0.

Comment: Are SP and VTOR definitely pointing to sane places at this point?

Comment: It looks like I managed to overcome this problem myself. My bootloader implementation originally initialized FMC in the wrong way. As a result all memory read attempts returned 0x000000. After fixing managed to proceed.